# Full media absolute paths with graphene-django

Tags: django, graphene-django

I'm currently switching from using DRF to django-graphene while using boto3 and s3 for media content. When using DRF, the file field would come back with the full path for the media inside of the s3 bucket. However, graphene-django file fields are only returning relative paths.

For instance with DRF a file field would come back with it's full url like:

```
https://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/logos/logos_2019-11-07_172356.1808000000.png
```

But with graphene-django it's coming back as:

`/logos/logos_2019-11-07_172356.1808000000.png`

Is there a middleware that needs to be added? Or do I need to create my own scaler to deal with this? I'm very new to graphene-django and graphql in general. So any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a custom field to build the full URL as follows.

```
class FileType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
       model = FileModel

    storage_url = graphene.String()

   def resolve_storage_url(self, info):
       return f"https://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/{self.url}"
```

Then query the `storage_url` field from the frontend.

Comment: Yes I suppose that will work. I was hoping for something less manual, like how DRF does it

Comment: If you build the full URL when you are doing the mutation and store it, that would be a better solution. You can make your own scalar which needs more work to do.

Comment: By the way, did you try to return the URL like `self.image.url`?

Answer (score 1):

As Ijharul Islam mentioned, you should add a custom field, but:
To get the url from different buckets, and even from private objects (you need a key to access the file), I would suggest to access the field "url" inside the field in your model that contains the file.

Ex: Here I have a custom User model, with the field "photo_file" in my models:

```
class UserType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        only_fields = ('id', 'username', 'first_name',
                       'last_name', 'photo_file',)

    def resolve_photo_file(self, info):
        if self.photo_file and self.photo_file.url:
            return f"{self.photo_file.url}"

        else:
            return None
```